# How to fix error when comparing validation fields in angular form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am creating a custom validation to compare dates and print an error when the end date is less than the start date. I think I am doing everything right but I am getting an error.
It spans up an error when I run my application. The error has to do with the fact that I am using a custom validation function. But that is how see everyone do it

My Error

```
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pristine' of null
        at FormGroup.campaign_period [as validator] (app.component.ts:10)
        at FormGroup.AbstractControl._runValidator (forms.js:3378)
        at FormGroup.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:3332)
        at new FormGroup (forms.js:4268)
        at FormBuilder.group (forms.js:7812)
ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.



 Example:


<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <input formControlName="firstName">
</div>

In your class:

this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstName: new FormControl()
});
```

---

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.signupForm = this._fb.group({
          firstname   : ['', Validators.required],
          lastname    : ['', Validators.required],
          date        : ['', Validators.required],
          gender      : ['', Validators.required],
          address     : ['', Validators.required],
          email       : ['', Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.EMAIL_REGEXP)],
           city       : ['', Validators.required],
           state      : ['', Validators.required],
           country    : ['', Validators.required],
           hobbies    : this._fb.array([this.createHobbies()]),
           campaigndateForm: this._fb.group({
             startDate: ['', Validators.required],
             endDate: ['', Validators.required]
           }, { validator: campaign_period })
    });

  }
```

---

```
function campaign_period(c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} | null {
  let start_date = c.get('stateDate');
  let end_date = c.get('endDate');
  if (start_date.pristine || end_date.pristine) {
     return null;
  }
    if (end_date.value > start_date.value) {
      return null;
  }
  return { 'range': true };
}

<div class="date_field_width" >
  <mat-form-field>
    <input formControlName="startDate" matInput [matDatepicker]="startdate" placeholder="Start date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startdate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #startdate></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input formControlName="endDate" matInput [matDatepicker]="enddate" placeholder="End a date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="enddate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #enddate></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  let start_date = c.get('stateDate');
  let end_date = c.get('endDate');
  if (start_date.pristine || end_date.pristine) {
     return null;
  }
```

The error is when you access `pristine` of `start_date` or `end_date` and pristine is not reachable if either `start_date` or `end_date` is null.

You need to check `start_date` and `end_date` before check `pristine`